# How to configure code completition for dojo 1.10.4 on Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: dojo, aptana3

I'm new to using Aptana Studio 3 with dojo 1.10.4.
I'd like to have code completition, so I've installed the relative ruble from github (https://github.com/ben8p/dojo.ruble), by accessing the menù "command -> bundle development -> install bundle".
The download of the ruble was ok, but I don't still be able to have the code completition on js files.
Can anyone help me?
Very thanks.
Fabio.

Answer (score 0):

I created this parser tool for dojo on version 1.7 back in the days;

https://github.com/mschr/dojos/blob/master/README
https://github.com/mschr/dojos/tree/master/util/docscripts

You may drop this file into your project and you will probably have most functionality as it is in the 1.1X today, or fixup the php generator to work with the current dojo.build docparser

**https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mschr/dojos/master/util/docscripts/jsdoc/api.hdr.js**